# Django Models - Ordering ManyToManyFields based on user input

Tags: python, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I come here with mixed answers from other websites or even ChatGPT, so I wanted to gather more information by asking here!

I am in need of generating an ordered List from a selection of ManyToManyFields, **in which the order criteria is defined by the selection order in the user interface**.

```
class InputConfig(models.Model):
    validations = models.ManyToManyField(ValidatorConfig, blank=True)
    transformers = models.ManyToManyField(TransformerConfig, blank=True)
```

The relevant part of my model looks like this. This would generate a selection box in Django that lets you select available validations or transformers, but these need to be executed in an ordered manner, which can change from client to client. What functionality would allow me to make an ordered selection?

LEVEL UP

Having solved this issue, can I make an ordered selection that allows me to **select validators and transformers in a single list**? This would allow even greater flexibility! So this would return a list, ordered again by user input.

```
[Transformer1, Validator1, Transformer2, Transformer3, Validator2...]
```

I hope I made myself clear, if not I'm glad to follow up debate and conversation!
Thanks for reading <3

I haven't tried much, but to define a value in each field which I use to order my query, but its not dynamic enough. Each context has different requirements

Comment: How would you specify the order as input?

Comment: I would order them by drag and drop on to a box, so selection order becomes return order as well